# Why is it required to configure a port with certificate in Netsh for WCF self-host w/ transport security?

Tags: windows, wcf, certificate

Why does one have to configure a port with a certificate when self-hosting a WCF service that uses transport security?

I understand SSL/HTTP and that the certificate is needed for it.  However, in non-WCF contexts, I can just create an SSL socket and assign the certificate programmatically.  For the WCF self-host case, why is the extra netsh step required (as in link below)?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733791.aspx

Comment: I ask because I didn't realize this requirement and have been banging my head for the last day trying to figure out why basic SSL negotiation wasn't working :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only in the case of HTTP.

That setup required for HTTP.SYS so no matter if you are using IIS or self-hosting, HTTP.SYS running in Kernel mode will require setup.